# Moq callback for ReturnsAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I'm currently refactoring API to async actions and I need to refactor the tests for async. I have similar case as in the [Moq documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods):

```
// returning different values on each invocation
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var calls = 0;
mock.Setup(foo => foo.GetCountThing())
    .Returns(() => calls)
    .Callback(() => calls++);
// returns 0 on first invocation, 1 on the next, and so on
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.GetCountThing());
```

And I need to change it to:

```
// returning different values on each invocation
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var calls = 0;
mock.Setup(foo => foo.GetCountThingAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(calls)
    .Callback(() => calls++);
// returns 0 on first invocation, 1 on the next, and so on
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.GetCountThingAsync());
```

But as the `ReturnAsync()` doesn't support lambda yet, the callback is called, but apparently in different context and thus the variable remains the value for the next call instead of being increased. Is there a way how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example you are passing a lambda to the `Returns` method, and that lambda is re-evaluated each time the mocked method is called. Because of this, you can actually combine `Callback` and `Returns`

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var calls = 0;
mock.Setup(foo => foo.GetCountThing())
    .Returns(() => calls++);

Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.GetCountThing());
```

In the second example you are passing the value 0 into the `ReturnsAsync` method, so that is why the mock returns zero each time. Although `ReturnsAsync` doesn't support passing a `Func`, you can still use `Returns` like so

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var calls = 0;
mock.Setup(foo => foo.GetCountThingAsync())
    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(calls++));

Console.WriteLine(await mock.Object.GetCountThingAsync());
```