# Using WeakReferenceMessenger to send a message with a value to an async callback

Tags: c#, xamarin, messaging, mvvm-toolkit

I've been trying to implement WeakReferenceMessenger to send messages in my Xamarin app. I've successfully used it to send messages to an async callback using the following...

Message class:

```
public class MyMessage : CollectionRequestMessage<Task>
{
    public MyMessage() { }
}
```

Register command:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, MyCallbackAsync);
```

Send command:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(typeof(MyMessage));
```

And extending IMessengerExtensions:

```
public static partial class IMessengerExtensions
{
    public static void Register<T>(this IMessenger messenger, object recipient, Func<Task> asyncAction) where T : CollectionRequestMessage<Task>
    {
        messenger.Register<T>(recipient, (r, m) =>
        {
            var task = asyncAction();
            m.Reply(task);
        });
    }
}
```

I've also sent messages with values to non-async callbacks as follows...

Message class:

```
public class MyMessageWithString : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public MyMessageWithString(string value) : base(value) { }
}
```

Register command:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessageWithString>(this, (r, m) => MyCallbackWithString(m.Value));
```

Send command:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyMessageWithString), new object[] { "Hello world" }) as MyMessageWithString;

WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(instance);
```

Unfortunately, I also need to send a message with a value to an async callback but I can't see how to pass a value using CollectionRequestMessage (it doesn't seem to expose a Value property as ValueChangedMessage does). Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: See if this guide helps you https://medium.com/@freakyali/messengers-api-in-net-73ce3382008d

Answer (score -1):

> Unfortunately, I also need to send a message with a value to an async
> callback but I can't see how to pass a value using
> CollectionRequestMessage (it doesn't seem to expose a Value property
> as ValueChangedMessage does). Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

About async callback, you can use the Callback method of the Moq framework and refer to this case: [Moq callback for ReturnsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851164/moq-callback-for-returnsasync).